# Productivity of short adjectives derived from those of -ний type

Tags: прилагательные

For most adjectives, a basic ground form to derive the rest in a paradigm seems to be that of Masculine Singular and they therefore can be divided into ***-ый,*** ***-ой***  and -***ий***-types.

Historically and stylistically, the shortened adjectives seem to be more archaic and related to a higher / poetic style. This comprises both relative and qualitative adjectives (although not possessive ones), even the adjectives of ***-ой***-type (though these seem to be less productive).

[The shortened forms of adjectives (especially those derived from relative 'ancestors') are then usually to be post-positioned, but now I deliberately skip this nuance for the sake of the completeness].

Cf:

***зéлено яблоко <=> зелёное яблоко (зелёный)***

***(*?) сóлев холм  <=>    солевой холм***

***(*?) челюстнен скат <=> челюстной скат (= контур)**

***рдян ог(о)нь  <=>   рдяной огонь***

but:

***синий кит*** < = > ????

I am not mentioning here the archaic and poetic combined formes, such as ***зелено-яблоко*** and ***рдян-огнь***, because the usage of ***-*** in Russian since, say, the 17th century seems to be the other topic.

Syntaxically, the shortened forms mostly convey a meaning of perfective utterance:

***Яблоко зелено. Пол стеклянен. Огонь багрян.***

But what about the shortened adjectives of the -***ий***-types? They seem to be non-productive, but is it a later development?

For some adjectives (mainly relative) the shortened forms are imaginable, eg. ***мужний, братний, весенний, зимний*** can be imagined as *мужен, *братнен, *весенен and *зимнен (at least, as elements of compound words).

But what about the shortened forms of relative adjectives ending in ***-ний***? Some are imaginable (e.g. those derived from ***давний,*** ***давнишний, давешний, вышний, внешний***) but the others are not.

To mention a few;

***синий***

***верхний***

***крайний***

***сторонний***

***дольний***

***ворóний***, etc?

Comment: I've checked some grammar sources and they say that relative adjectives do not have a shortened form.

Comment: And here we see them at least in such examples as ***стеклянен, оловянн, деревянен***

Comment: no they are not productive anymore, and yes they used to be productive. *синь* ("blue"), *лъжь* ("false, unreliable"), *истиньнь* ("true, reliable"), *дольнь* ("low; mundane"), *горьнь* ("high; upper; elated") are all attested.

Comment: @Manjusri, it depends on how you tell a valid word from an invalid. Many grammar books will declare them as invalid just on the basis of being produced from relative adjectives. Anyway only few of possible short adjectives are really used and don't sound weird. Considering your original question, such adjectives of -ий type as близкий, дальний, широкий, узкий, мелкий have valid and commonly used shortened form: близок, далек, широк, узок, мелок.

Comment: @Manjusri, you could use _деревянен_ in a metaphorical sense: "голос Пилата был давно уже пуст, деревянен, как колотушка" where it describes the _quality_ of something and thus becomes _qualitative_. In its main sense you can't use its short form, e.g. saying *_пол деревянен_ would be ungrammatical. Sames goes for _стеклянен, оловянен_.

Comment: @AlexVB The forms of -кий are relatively easy.

Comment: @Serey Slepov What's so ungrammatical of e.g. пол (был) деревянен и обшарпан?

Comment: Критерий прост–так не говорят ("деревянен").

Comment: Ну как же "не говорят", когда говорят... то есть пишут?

Comment: @Manjusri - Написать можно что угодно. Тем не менее, большинство носителей русского языка (исключая Вас, очевидно) согласятся, что "пол деревянен" - это неправильно, "так не говорят". А вот и исключение (куда ж без них!): _Немолод дом и деревянен, //
О нем известно наперед: //
Сквозь щели у закрытых ставен //
Никто в нем никого не ждет._ (Ширяев Николай) http://litcentr.in.ua/publ/269-1-0-633

Comment: Этот пример не отменяет сказанного: "дом деревянен" все равно звучит "неправильно" и создает слегка комичный эффект, как бы намекая: "подождите печалиться, стихотворение в целом веселое!"

Comment: Ч.Т.Д. Узус и корпусные методы как таковые малоприменимы к creative writing. К слову: в приводимом Вами примере комичного эффекта не чувствую (но это немного из другой оперы).

Comment: А вдуматься, то с точки зрения психолингвистики становится ясно, почему там появляется комический эффект. Хороший пример, благодарю.

Answer (score 4):

Adjectives in -ий are not that different from other adjectives when it comes to producing short forms.

"Кит синь, вода синя, море сине" - those are quite normal short forms of синий.

Верхний, крайний, сторонний and дольний (did you mean дальний?) are all relative adjectives and hence do not have short forms (although they are potentially possible: верхен, краен, сторонен, дален).

Ворóний is a possessive adjective and -ий is not an ending in the morphological sense. Ворóний has a null ending. Other examples of words with the same declension type: заячий, лисий, третий, весь.

Possessive adjectives are a subclass of relative adjectives and hence do not have short or comparative forms.

Дальний has a near-synonym далёкий which is qualitative and does have short forms: далёк, далека, далеко, далеки.

To sum up, only qualitative adjectives have short, comparative and superlative forms, regardless of their declension type (-ий, -ый, -ой, null). And that makes sense: something can be more or less blue but something cannot be more or less 'top' (верхний).

Qualitative/relative are two ends of a scale and not a binary classification. E.g. апельсиновый is normally relative (to orange) but one can say, for the sake of a pun:

Это наиапельсиновейший напиток в мире!

Comment: *вороний* has a non-null ending *-ий* in nominative (which changes with case and gender); *дольний* means "lower; mundane" and is not a synonym to *далёкий* ("far, remote"); having comparative and superlative forms is orthogonal to having a short form.

Comment: @Quassnoi, google "окончание притяжательных прилагательных" (note that I did not add "нулевое"). My top result reads: "Притяжательные прилагательные мужского рода в именительном  
и винительном падежах единственного числа имеют **нулевое окончание** (дедушкин, волчий)". I'd be interested to see links that prove the opposite.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I never said дОльний was a synonym of далёкий. I said that about дАльний, e.g.: дальний берег / далёкий берег are essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Quassnoi, in Zaliznyak's Grammatical Dictionary of Russian the symbols "!" ('no short form') and '~' ('no comparative/superlative form') often come together (more often than not). So there is definitely a correlation there.

Comment: I mean дольний as opposite of горний. Are you sure that in Russian an object cannot be more or less 'top' (as well as left, right and / or, say, made of metal)?

Comment: And what about such forms as воронин, волчьин, лисьин, зайкин?

Comment: _Воронин, зайкин, Олин_ etc (from ворона, зайка, Оля) are also posessive adjectives. They mean 'belonging to this particular person/animal' while _вороний, заячий_ mean 'typical of / made of crows/hares' in general. E.g. you can say _заячий мех, вороний клюв_ as all hares have fur and all crows have beaks. In the famous Bazhov's tale you would find  _воронин сыр_  (Crow's cheese) but you cannot say _вороний сыр_ because there is no such thing ('cheese made of crows') _Козий сыр_ (from _коза_ ,  goat) is perfectly valid though.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov You probably meant Krylov, or Aesop, but not Bazhov, as the author of "The Fox and the Crow" tale.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov Are you sure that  ***синь*** is the short form of Masculine from ***синий*** and not the noun?

Comment: @Manjusri - It's both. Examples of the masculine short form: 

  - _Туапсинский залив был свеж и прекрасно синь, как море в приключенческих романах Стивенсона._ Эдуард Лимонов. Книга воды (2002)
  - _Конечно, дворцы на своих местах. Екатерининский ― так же синь, Александровский ― жёлт._ Александр Ласкин. Ангел, летящий на велосипеде // «Звезда», 2001

I recommend the Russian National Corpus for finding example usages of words and their grammatical forms:

 - http://ruscorpora.ru

Answer (score 1):

If you are intersted in looking-up theoretical proper shortened forms of Russian adjectives, online dictionaries might come in handy.

For example you can use an online version of Zaliznyak's dictionary or the Wiktionary (I surmise that the latter is based on the former):

[http://www.morfologija.ru/словоформа/братний](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/братний](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

I have just two remarks:

- as these are formal dictionaries  they follow formal grammar, so no shortened forms of relative adjectives;
- many of the shortened forms listed in these dictionaries look awkward and are barely used in the modern written or spoken language (i.e. shortened forms of крайний, ближний etc.; N.B. крайне as in "крайне плохой" is an adverb).

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting, though, that the short Masculin forms of e. g. крайний and братний are missing in Zaliznyak's chart. Which makes me doubt the productivity of синь as a short form for синий.

Comment: @Manjusri, "краен" is listed in the Wiktionary as theoretically possible. I personally have never heard this word, but I haven't heard "крайна" as well.
As for "синь" the word may be a noun as in морская синь and an adjective as in нос его был синь (rare usage, though).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this info might be interesting.
Краткие прилагательные – особые несклоняемые, предикативные формы **качественных** прилагательных.
I have found examples on the ruscorpora.ru

> Вода была ласково-спокойна и **весело-синя**, светлея лишь косыми гладкими полосами в местах течения и переходя в густо-синий глубокий цвет на горизонте. [А. И. Куприн. Гранатовый браслет (1911)
>
> Как **синя** ночь для человека, отошедшего от костра, и как красна голая дорожка на освещенном зеленом лугу; конечно, эти явления, хотя и без анализа их, издавна знакомы людям. [К. С. Петров-Водкин. Моя повесть. Часть 2.
>
> Ветер был виден, он был **синь**, он рвал воду и нес ее с собой по воздуху, и вода кипела. [Б. А. Пильняк. Заволочье (1925)]
>
> Тогда была луна, снег был **синь**, горы и глетчеры уходили во мглу, снег сыпался и звенел, казалось под луной, что эти люди на луне, ― скелет «Свердрупа» распух от инея. [Б. А. Пильняк. Заволочье (1925)]
>
> Залив был **синь**. И камни, грея спины,
> На жарком солнце спали под горой.
> [И. А. Бунин. Бог полдня (1908.08.12)]

Какие прилагательные **не имеют кратких форм**?

Большинство прилагательных в русском языке имеют и полную, и краткую форму. К словам-исключениям, у которых есть **только полная** форма, относятся:

1. Прилагательные с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами и суффиксами, несущими подчеркнуто объективно суждение

> темненький, широченный, крохотный

2. Некоторые названия цветов

> оливковый, малиновый, шоколадный

3. Прилагательные, называющие масти животных

   > вороной, пегий, гнедой
4. Качественные прилагательные с суффиксами -ск-, -н-, -ов-(-ев-), образованные от относительных прилагательных

> товарищеский, ручной, вековой

5. Отглагольные прилагательные, образованные при помощи суффикса -л-

> бывалый, прошлый, талый

6. Некоторые многозначные прилагательные образуют краткую форму **только к одному из значений**. Так, например, у прилагательного фальшивый краткая форма есть при употреблении слова в значении «неискренний» – фальшивые чувства – чувства фальшивы, тогда как в значении «ненастоящий, поддельный» не  употребляется краткая форма – фальшивая купюра.
7. Только в краткой форме употребляются прилагательные

> горазд, надобен, должен, рад, одинехонек/одинешенек, маловат, радехонек /радешенек, великоват и другие.